# How to get fields in top_hits aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, duplicates

I have elasticsearch cluster - version 1.3.0. The index documents of this cluster doesn't have _source enabled hence when retrieving hits, I usually get based on "fields" parameter in my request.

Now I am implementing `top_hits` aggregation for a duplicate grouping functionality. I would like to get fields in the `top_hits` result which I couldn't do it now since `_source` isn't enabled by default in my mapping. Could you please suggest me a option/work around to achieve this with out changing existing mapping?

I didn't find it in the [top-hits aggregation doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_supported_per_hit_features). Any help on this much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [script fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/search-request-script-fields.html):

```
  "aggs": {
    "sample": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 1,
        "script_fields": {
          "field1": {
            "script": "doc['field1']"
          },
          "field2": {
            "script": "doc['field2']"
          }
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**But**, if `field1` or `field2` are analyzed, you would need a sub-field that should keep a `not_analyzed` version of the field. Why? Because, if the normal field is analyzed in any way, the `doc['field']` call will return the analyzed terms, not the initial content that was indexed.

Something like this:

```
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      }, 
      "properties": {
        "field1": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "notAnalyzed": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And the query:

```
  "aggs": {
    "sample": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 1,
        "script_fields": {
          "field1": {
            "script": "doc['field1.notAnalyzed']"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot. Though, could this add load to the memory of elasticsearch nodes as they are caching document fields?

Comment: Hm, I think it will affect the response time of the queries by using CPU time for longer. Scripts are not so fast.

Comment: @AndreiStefan How can I get nested field in this ? i.e in script_fields If I want to get a field which is nested inside another field.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I have used params._source and it got solved.